# Database indexing - what is the purpose of indexing primary keys

Tags: sql, database, indexing

From what I have read, indexing is like writing index page at the front of the book to make sure the db doesnt have to go through all the pages.

If primary key is indexed, wouldnt it be exactly same as going through the entire book because they are all unique anyways so the categorization within the index of primary key is same as the number of documents. If so, what is the purpose of indexing primary keys if there is no performance benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key *is* an index -- keys are indexes! It's just a special name for a special kind of index which is always unique, and which may have an automatically assigned value.

In some databases, the rows are sometimes (or always) stored in the same order as the primary key. In these situations, the primary key may not need to be separately indexed -- the order of the rows is enough of an index on its own.

In some other databases, the primary key is not treated differently. The rows are stored in an arbitrary order -- perhaps in the order they were last modified, for example. In these situations, an index is needed on the primary key to look up the rows.